# XmlDocument Validation not working

Tags: c#, xsd, xmldocument, xml-validation

I have an XmlDocument that I build in memory. I have an XSD document stored in my database. I get a stream for that XSD document and try to validate XmlDocument. But the validation never works. It always validates even if I add invalid nodes in XmlDocument.

Also, I specify the TargetNameSpace value in xml document as it is there in XSD. But the validation still does not happen.

```
       XmlSchemaSet schemaSet = new XmlSchemaSet();
       schemaSet.Add("http://tempuri.org/test.xsd", XmlReader.Create(stream));
       schemaSet.Compile();

       XmlSchema xmlSchema = null;
       foreach (XmlSchema schema in schemaSet.Schemas())
       {
            xmlSchema = schema;
       }

       //setting targetnamespace as it is there in xsd
       rootElement.SetAttribute("xmlns", xmlSchema.TargetNamespace);

       xmlDoc.Schemas.Add(xmlSchema);
       string error = string.Empty;
       xmlDoc.Validate((sender, e) =>
       {
           switch (e.Severity)
           {
                case XmlSeverityType.Error:
                     error = e.Message;
                break;
                case XmlSeverityType.Warning:
                     LogWarning(e.Message);
                     break;
           }
        });
```

The error string is always empty. Am I doing something wrong over here?

Comment: You should probably tag this question with the appropriate programming language.

Comment: You're not adding any elements to your xmlDoc. You sure an empty document isn't valid with your schema?

Comment: Thanks for suggestion. But I am adding elements to my XmlDocument.

Comment: You will not get an error if your root element doesn't match a globally defined XML element in your XSD. I suggest to do additional troubleshooting, and then, if still needed, update your question with details. What I would do, make sure that the schema set compiles (IsCompiled=true). I would serialize the XML as a file, and inspect it to make sure you do get something, and that it matches what you have as a root element. If you're still not good, try to apply the same code against some sample XML/XSD pair from the internet (public) and then update your question with more comprehensive data.

Comment: The xml was huge so I had to write it to disk and thereafter I used this link(http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/as3tta56.aspx) and it worked fine. Thanks anyways.